# Programming a PID controller in c language to control the inrush current of a dc motor

Tags: c, stm32, pid-controller

I am here to seek help from the community to develop a program in C language that would allow me to limit the inrush current of a DC motor while controlling the PWM at these terminals.

The motor in question is a 50W 24V and I want to limit the current to 2.5A.

For that, I developed an electronic board with a microcontroller from STMicroelectronics, the STM32F31C4T6.

The current measurement is done with an adc.

When I arrive in the function of the PID I am lost, I do not know how to limit the current and at the same time manage the PWM

Here is the beginning of the code I wrote, it just misses the PWM that I send at the beginning as an argument of the function :

```
#include "PID.h"


/* constants for PID */
const float Kp = 0.01;  // The value for Proportional gain
const float Ki = 0.01;  // The value for Integral gain
const float Kd = 0.001; // The value for Differential gain
const int Set_Point = 1950; // The ADC reference point we are aiming to regulate to

uint32_t tabDuty[50];

int i =0;

void PWM_Duty_Change(current)
{
    /* Global Variables for PID */
    float d_Temp = 0;   // This stores the old ADC value
    float i_Temp = 0;   // This stores the accumulated Integral value
    float PWM_Temp = 0; 
    
    
    //Local variables for PID
    float iMax = 100;       // Used to prevent integral wind-up
    float iMin = -100;  // Used to prevent integral wind-up
    float Err_Value;        // Holds the calculated Error value
    float P_Term;               // Holds the calculated Proportional value
    float I_Term;               // Holds the calculated Integral value
    float D_Term;               // Holds the calculated Differential value
    int new_current_ADC_value;  // Holds the new ADC value
    float PWM_Duty; // Holds the new PWM value

    
    new_current_ADC_value = current;

    Err_Value = (Set_Point - new_current_ADC_value);

    // This calculates Proportional value, Kp is 
    //multiplied with Err_Value and the result is assigned to P_Term
    P_Term = Kp * Err_Value;

    // Prepare Integral value, add the current error 
    //value to the integral value and assign the total to i_Temp
    i_Temp += Err_Value;

    // Prevents integral wind-up, limits i_Temp 
    //from getting too positive or negative
    if (i_Temp > iMax)
        {i_Temp = iMax;}
    else if (i_Temp < iMin)
        {i_Temp = iMin;}

    // Calculates the Integral value, Ki is 
    //multiplied with i_Temp and the result is assigned to I_Term
    I_Term = Ki * i_Temp;

    // Calculates Differential value, Kd is multiplied with 
    //(d_Temp minus new_ADC_value) and the result is assigned to D_Term
        
    // The new_ADC_value will become the old ADC value 
    //on the next function call, this is assigned to d_Temp so it can be used
    D_Term = Kd * (d_Temp - Err_Value);
    d_Temp = Err_Value;

    /****** Now we have the P_Term, I_Term and D_Term *****/
    PWM_Duty = PWM_Temp - (P_Term + I_Term + D_Term);
        
    // PWM overflow prevention
    if (PWM_Duty > 90)
        {PWM_Duty = 90;}
    else if (PWM_Duty < 10)
        {PWM_Duty = 10;}

    // Adjusts the PWM duty cycle
    adjust_PWM(PWM_Duty);
    // Assigns the current PWM duty cycle value to PWM_Temp
    PWM_Temp = PWM_Duty;
    
}
```

If you need more information do not hesitate to ask me.

I thank you for all the help you can give me

Comment: You need to establish a unit used by all calculations. For example PWM clock ticks. Then re-scale everything which is in the wrong unit to the established unit. You also need to specify an acceptable resolution/error margin. Then pick ADC, PWM, passive components and clock accordingly. And ideally you also have to pick a cyclic timer interval in which you read ADC values and update the PWM. If you haven't established any of this, then no amount of programming will help. Start with the specification, like always.

Comment: @Lundin All this has already been set up, I read the current value with a timer every 4.16µs just after sending the pwm to the motor terminals. However, for the acceptable resolution/error margin I don't really see how to set this up. For me, it would be the iMax and iMin variables that manage this.

Comment: Again, no programming in the world can change the hardware - you can't just hack away without a specification. You need to specify a resolution on resistors, clock, ADC voltage reference... Once that is done, you can see if your MCU is suitable, or if you need a greater resolution on the ADC. (PWM resolution is rarely an issue since it's gonna be 32 bits or so.) And only from there on you can decide how to write the PID software: scaling factors, variable sizes and so on.

Comment: Because I don't see any rescaling from ADC reads to PWM duty cycles. So what's the unit that the PID works with? It's ok if it's just some abstract raw unit, but then you will have to re-scale to duty cycles in the end. And how to do all of this re-scaling cannot be answered without knowing the specification. If you use some 0.01% resistors and a delta sigma ADC, it will do no good if the firmware tosses that accuracy out the window. I mean what's this: `PWM_Duty > 90`, you only have 90 PWM timer cycles?

Comment: PWM_Duty is the duty cycle in percentage, it corresponds to the percentage of the voltage at the motor terminals. 

STM32F31C4T6 uses a 12 bits ADC which is more than enough for my application, it works at a frequency of 14MHz.

As for the system frequency, it is 48 MHz, which is more than enough for this application.

The rise time of the motor inrush current to reach 2.5A is 4ms, so I have plenty of time to process the information.

Comment: So how do you go from 12 bit ADC reads to a floating point percentage value and from that percentage value to duty cycles?

Comment: And also the resolution by the ADC, PWM and code is determined by the clock source. Some STM32 have quite bad internal oscillators. At 48MHz I'm assuming external quartz?

Comment: The ADC only measures the current drawn by the motor.

The duty cycle is sent by a man-machine interface, interpreted by the code and then applied to the output of the microcontroller. The duty cycle is multiplied at a voltage of 3.3V. This voltage is then sent to a half-bridge driver which takes care of cutting a 24V voltage using the pwm of the microcontroller. We then find the voltage cut to the terminals of the motor.

Comment: No I'm using the internal oscillator

Comment: Re-scaling from one unit to another, assuming they are all linear, has to be done with plain straight line equations, where you need to know the min and max values of the scales. I don't see any of that in the code, it has to be done somewhere, you can't just grab a raw ADC value from 0 to 4095 and then wish that it's actually a floating point value from 0.00...f to 100.0...f. You have to actually re-scale it somewhere.

Comment: And since you are using some internal cheap oscillator, you don't actually have 12 bits but 4096 +/- x. Same with your periodic reads and duty cycle. You'll have to code with that inaccuracy in mind. Meaning that keeping track of a bunch of floating point decimals for floating point accuracy is overkill. Note how I haven't even mentioned the PID parts yet, you need to be standing on solid ground first of all.

Comment: _Side note:_ You have a comment: `Calculates the Integral value, Ki is multiplied with i_Temp and the result is assigned to I_Term` Then, you have the code: `I_Term = Ki * i_Temp;` This comment is mostly replicating the code, but in text. The code is the _how_. The comment should be the _what/why_. I'd change the comment to (e.g.): `Calculate the integral value` Or, `Calculate the integral value -- the integral value is ...` Many/most comments are like that.

Comment: I would give up and limit the current with hardware:)

Comment: @MartinJames It's actually not that advanced at all but you need to have a proper engineering approach. I've designed several very similar PI(D) systems for hydraulic valves/solenoids which used pure fixed point arithmetic and lousy 8-bit or 16-bit MCUs which didn't have a tenth of the processing power of a Cortex M4. The key to making it work is to realize that the whole control loop hw+sw is a chain which doesn't get better than the weakest link.

Answer (score 0):

A PID is a linear controller. What you want is to apply a nonlinear constraint on it, hence limiting the voltage. This is unfortunately not possible. What is mostly done in practice is setting a limit on the input signal, hoping that it will not have much impact on the controller.

If you need at all costs to design a controller that takes into account the maximal voltage, then you should have a look at optimal control theory.

Edit

Another way to see it is to look at how is a PID designed. PID are basically a linear filter in the frequency domain. But in the frequency domain you cannot set a time-domain constraint. You can play with gain and with some prior knowledge make sure that with your supply and maximum input, you’ll never reach the threshold of your actuator. This is only possible if know beforehand the maximal input of your system.

Comment: PID is not "linear" controller as it has integral and differential part.

Comment: Yes, but this result in a linear differential equation. If you write the difference equation, you only get linear terms. y[k] = … y[k-i] + … u[k-1]. The PID is linear in the frequency domain, which is the way a PID is designed.